# Creating 20+ Azure Resource Group with Locks

Tags: json, powershell, azure, azure-cli, azure-resource-group

Creating 20+ Azure Resource Group with Locks two locations in the US (West and East). I can not fine `JSON` template or `cli` template which would let me create them through user prompt in the terminal or through JSON parameter in the console. I cant be creating one by one for both the regions using

`New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rgName -Location $locName`

Closest i saw in MS site is the below -

## variables

```
`$labPrefix = "Mlab"
$labnumber = "2017"
$labsubnet = "55"
$rgName = $labPrefix + $labnumber #New resource group name
$locName = "West Europe" # Loation of new resource group
$saName = $rgName.Replace("-","").tolower() 
$saType="Standard_LRS" # Storage account type`
```

If i was creating RG as Mlab2017 - this would work. but mine would have 4 different labPrefix  and 4 different labnumber. I cant seem to find a better solutions for this. any help on creating the json array with or shell script array to pass and create the RG with Locks will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you dudnt really specify what you want to achieve, its really hard to help you without that information

Answer (score 1):

You could use template to create resource groups firstly, then you could use Power Shell to lock resource groups in specific area.  For example:

```
$location1 = "eastus"
$location2 = "westus"
$rg=Get-AzureRmResourceGroup |Where-Object{($_.Location -eq $location1) -or ($_.Location -eq $location2)}
$rgnames = $rg.ResourceGroupName
foreach ($rgname in $rgnames)
{
    $lockname = $rgname+"lock"
    New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockName $lockname -LockLevel CanNotDelete -ResourceGroupName $rgname
}
```

You also could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources).